# AngularJS - Proven way of handling ng-model data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a form, and I'm trying to bind date from it in the `angularjs - controller` so I can pass it into the `djangorestframework` view to do more stuff with it.

Now my problem is that I don't understand how to properly bind data from the `datetimepicker` input filed in the controller, I'll show up my form and small part of the controller, as far as I understand this is that I need to have `ng-model` on the input field and put a `function` on the Submit button, and that is clear for me but the part in the controller I don't understand, so how can I properly bind this, can someone please help me, thank you, controller is written in coffee script.

```
<div class="flex-grid"
         ng-controller="FilterContactsListCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="id_select_date">Select Date: *</label>
                    <div class="full-size">
                        <div class="input-control full-size text"
                            data-role="datepicker" date-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                            <input id="id_select_date" ng-model="selectDate"/>
                            <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <button class="button primary" ng-click="doAction()">
                    {% trans "Submit" %}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
app = angular.module 'vinclucms.sales'

app.controller 'FilterContactsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'LeadContact'
  ($scope, $rootScope, LeadContact) ->
    $scope.doAction = ()->
      filterLeadContactList()

    filterLeadContactList = () ->
      $scope.selectDate = null
      $scope.doAction = () ->
      # Do Action with date form the input field so I can pass it to the restapi view
      # this part I don't understand, how to bind this properly
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you don't pass any model to your controller. basicly your doAction() method can't do anything!

What I suggest is to change your form to use ng-submit and pass your model to controller.

```
<form ng-submit="doAction(selectDate)" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <label for="id_select_date">Select Date: *</label>
                <div class="full-size">
                    <div class="input-control full-size text"
                        data-role="datepicker" date-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                        <input id="id_select_date" ng-model="selectDate"/>
                        <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button class="button primary" type="submit">
                {% trans "Submit" %}
            </button>
</form>
```

As you notice I bring your button inside the form with type=submit.

Later in your controller you can access your data model like this :

```
 $scope.doAction = function(selectDate){
       console.log(selectDate); // You have access to your data now
     //Do what ever you want
  }
```